# Vagrant networking forwarded_port does not work

Tags: django, vagrant

I tried to setup sandbox for django development

I have forwarded the port in provision like this

```
config.vm.network:forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 8000
```

The server on guest started with

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 19, 2015 - 20:50:37
Django version 1.7.7, using settings 'my_site.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

then I open the web browser on host machine and type in

```
http://127.0.0.1:4567/
```

Failed to connect to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the dev server with

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

so that it listens to every interface of port 8000.

Comment: @Raislide, thanks for the answer. Then how could I access the server from my host machine ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to forward the port on Vagrant for accessing Django server from the host machine. What I usually do is start the server on the guest using

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and then access it from the host using 
"IP_address_of_guest_machine":8000

Comment: Hi Gaurang, thanks for the answer. That doesn't work for me. I started the server exactly the way you specified and find the ip address of guest machine with ifconfig to be say 10.0.2.15 and then open browser on the host machine and type in 10.0.2.15:8000 but connection fails. Have I done something wrong here? thanks again